# Add post processing logic on one method of all existing subclasses

Tags: python-3.x, oop, metaclass, magic-methods

In my codebase I have tens of already existing sub classes and I want to hook extra processing code into one public method inherited and overridden by all of those sub classes.

So I am trying to use `__init_subclass__` to do that, and this is the result:

```
def log(return_value):
  print('Logged:', return_value)


class Car:
  @staticmethod
  def logged_run(run): 

    def wrap(self):
      result = run(self)
      log(result)
      return result

    return wrap

  def run(self):
    return 'Car'
  
  def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
    super().__init_subclass__()
    cls.run = cls.logged_run(cls.run)

class AutoCar(Car):
  def run(self):
    return 'AutoCar'



auto = AutoCar()
car_type = auto.run()
```

Output:

```
Logged: AutoCar
```

I searched and did not find such usage for `__init_subclass__`, so is there anything wrong with such an implementation?

Do I need to call super `__init__subclass_` as in my example `super().__init_subclass__()`?

Do I need `**kwargs` in the parameter list of `__init_subclass__`?

Finally, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So, yes - your usage will produce you the right results  -
and, yes, your code would be better if it included the provisions you are in doubt in `__init_subclass__`. That way your class hierarchy will not be broken - `__init_subclass__` wise, if at any point someone on the same codebase decides to add some functionality via mixin classes there.

So, to sumarize: `__init_subclass__`  is automatically considered as a `classmethod`: no need for the decorator. And it will receive any kwargs passed as part of the `class` statement, but `metaclass` (it is consumed by the the class creation machinery) - and any non-recognized such parameters should be passed on to `super().__init_subclass__`:

```
  def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    cls.run = cls.logged_run(cls.run)
```

whether your code for `__init_subclass__` is before or after the call to `super()` does not matter for Python, and is up to you - it won't make any difference but if you have class initialisations designed to work in collaboratively.

It is also worth mentioning `__init_subclass__` is called before the metaclass `__init__`  method, if there is any, in a custom metaclass.

Also, even if working with strict typing, I think it would be redundant to annotate the return type (None) of `__init_subclass__`: your tools should know about it, as it is in the language spec, and human readers of the code will just see there is no return statement (along with no typing errors or warnings)

Apart from the workings of `__init_subclass__`, one peculiarity of your task is that it will wrap each version of a given method in each subclass in your hierarchy - if the methods use a `super()` call to themselves, the decorator will run multiple-times.

This is not easy to overcome if undesired, and have to be done "the hard way": setting a state somewhere (usually in an instance attribute)  to indicate the decorator has already "entered" and have an `if` guard clause at the decorator code so that it does not run more than once per call.

Comment: PS. you may also want to apply the `funtools.wraps` decorator to your `wrap` inner function - not needed in a minimal example here, of course.